# How can I set max buffer size for web socket client(Jetty) in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, jetty, ws

There is a function for connect web socket connection.

```
public void connectWebSocket(String vaHost, String apiKey) throws Exception{
        logger.info("========= CONNECT WEBSOCKET =========");
        String destUri = "ws://"+vaHost+"/metadata";

        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
        SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();

        client.start();
        client.setConnectTimeout(-1);

        URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
        ClientUpgradeRequest requestws = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        requestws.setSubProtocols("va-metadata");

        requestws.setTimeout(-1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        client.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(700000);
        client.connect(socket,echoUri,requestws);

        logger.info("=========WS Connecting to :"+echoUri);
}
```

You can find 'setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize' so that I set max buffer size to 700000.

But when an onMessageBuffer event occurs, I can find the exception like below.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.MessageTooLargeException: Binary message size [484666] exceeds maximum size [65536]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketPolicy.assertValidBinaryMessageSize(WebSocketPolicy.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.assertSanePayloadLength(Parser.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parseFrame(Parser.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parseSingleFrame(Parser.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

How can I set max buffer size for web socket connection to prevent exception?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your `SimpleEchoSocket` code, the problem seems to be within that code.

Comment: Also include what version of Jetty you are using.

Comment: Aren't there max message size settings separate from buffer size, did you try increasing those instead of buffer size? (setMaxBinaryMessageSize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 `setMaxTextMessageBufferSize`,`setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize`

Depending on the type of data you are sending:

```
    wsClient = new WebSocketClient(factory);
    wsClient.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(Args.maxTextSize);
    wsClient.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(Args.maxTextSize);
```

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-11/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/WebSocketClient.html

You also have the option of setting it on the `Session`:

```
CompletableFuture<Session> futureSession = wsClient.connect(webSocket, uri);


Session session = futureSession.get();

session.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(Args.maxTextSize);
session.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageSize(Args.maxTextSize);

session.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(Args.maxTextSize);
session.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageSize(Args.maxTextSize);
```

Comment: The order of resolution for policy can be viewed as: annotations, then session, then client.  But the value can be changed at runtime by using the session for the active connection.

Comment: Depending on your version of Jetty there can be as many as 6 settings (2 on ws-core, 2 on ws-api, 2 on ws-connection)

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I could fix my problem.