# How to resolve "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.MessageTooLargeException" for Java WebSocketStompClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sockjs, stomp-websocket

When I'm running a Java WebSocketStompClient, I got below error:
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.MessageTooLargeException: Text message size [73728] exceeds maximum size [65536]

Sample code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompFrameHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.Transport;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.frame.Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class HelloClient {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloClient.class);

    StompSession session;

    private final static WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();

    public ListenableFuture<StompSession> connect() {


        Transport webSocketTransport = new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient());

        List<Transport> transports = Collections.singletonList(webSocketTransport);

        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

        sockJsClient.setMessageCodec(new Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec());

        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);


        long[] hb = stompClient.getDefaultHeartbeat();
        boolean en = stompClient.isDefaultHeartbeatEnabled();
        long timeout = stompClient.getReceiptTimeLimit();

        String url = "https://www.test.com";
        return stompClient.connect(url, headers, new MyHandler());
    }

    public void subscribeMsg(StompSession stompSession) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        stompSession.subscribe("/topic/test", new StompFrameHandler() {
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
                return byte[].class;
            }

            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders stompHeaders, Object o) {
                logger.info("Received message " + new String((byte[]) o));
                String response = new String((byte[]) o);

            }
        });
    }


    private class MyHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
        public void afterConnected(StompSession stompSession, StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
            logger.info("Now connected");
            session = stompSession;
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            return session != null && session.isConnected();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Error happens when checking connection status, ", e);
            return false;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HelloClient helloClient = new HelloClient();

        ListenableFuture<StompSession> f = helloClient.connect();
        StompSession stompSession = f.get();
        helloClient.subscribeMsg(stompSession);


        while (true) {
            if (!helloClient.isConnected()) {
                logger.info("wss diconnected ");
                logger.info("need re-create ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to increase the limitation for a Java stomp websocket client? I found some not related answers  [How can I set max buffer size for web socket client(Jetty) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968609/how-can-i-set-max-buffer-size-for-web-socket-clientjetty-in-java) which are not suitable for stomp websocket client.

Also tried stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE); which doesn't work.

Comment: `stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(73729);` !?

Comment: "stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(73729);" doesn't work

Comment: ..with same exception!?

Comment: @xerx593, yes. The same exception. I add it right after "WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);"

Comment: ..with excatly same numbers??? ;)) `Text message size [73728] exceeds maximum size [65536]` ? (if so: wrong path, if not: you (just) need to know/estimate/test "max message size"

Comment: Yes! exactly same numbers. I've seen someone try setInboundMessageSizeLimit, but it solves another exception - "org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: The configured STOMP buffer size limit of 65536 bytes has been exceeded", not mine.